MUI NativeSelect blocks submit react hook form
I want to submit my form every time a change is made (when the value selected in a select is different for example).
But when I use NativeSelect from MUI, I can't do it..
Here is my code :
const onSubmit = (data: UpdateProspectNeufType) => console.log(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = watch((_value, {name, type}) => {
            if (type !== "change" || name === undefined) return;
            handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
        });
        return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
    }, [handleSubmit, watch]);

<Controller
                        control={control}
                        defaultValue={null}
                        name={"typeMaison"}
                        render={({field}) => (

                                <NativeSelect {...field} id={"typeMaison"} onChange={e => field.onChange(e.target.value)} value={field.value}>
                                    {typesMaison.map((typeMaison) => (
                                        <option key={typeMaison.id} value={typeMaison.id}>{typeMaison.libelle}</option>
                                    ))}
                                </NativeSelect>

                        )}
                    />

I would be very grateful for your help
However, if I remove the native it works but I really want to use NativeSelect or Select with native=true

If you really want to trigger the event everytime, I would recommend to remove the defaultValue and then just do the handleSubmit each time the onChange triggers, so it would look something like this:
<Controller
                control={control}
                name={"typeMaison"}
                render={({ field }) => (
                    <NativeSelect
                        {...field}
                        id={"typeMaison"}
                        onChange={(v) => {
                            field.onChange(v.target.value);
                            handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
                        }}
                        value={field.value}
                    >
                        {typesMaison.map((typeMaison) => (
                            <option key={typeMaison.id} value={typeMaison.id}>
                                {typeMaison.libelle}
                            </option>
                        ))}
                    </NativeSelect>
                )}
            />


I have done a test locally with success. You also omit the useEffect stuff, so it only fires on the onChange fn.
Hopes this helps you.
